# Como criar categorias para um Post type no Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Duvida simples, mas não encontro uma solução. Criei um tipo de Post chamado de "Produtos" no functions.php, mas ele não vem com categorias nativamente. O que eu coloco no functions para permitir que o usuário dê uma categoria para um Produto?
Consegui com o código:

> function demo_add_default_boxes() {
>
>     register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'produto');
>
>     register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'produto');
>
>
> }

Mas as categorias são compartilhadas com os Posts principais e os tipo de Post Produto. Como fazer para ter categorias diferentes para cada tipo de Post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode atingir o seu objetivo registrando uma taxonomia customizada para o seu *Custom Post* da seguinte forma (Vou assumir que o tipo de post se chama *produto*, e que a taxonomia se chama *tipo de produto*):

```
/* Action para o registro da Custom Taxonomy Tipo de Produto */
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_tax_tipo' );

/* Método para o registro da Custom Taxonomy Tipo de Produto */ 
function create_custom_tax_tipo(){
    $custom_tax_nome = 'tipo_de_produto';
    $custom_post_type_nome = 'produto';
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Tipo de Produto'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tipo')
    );
    register_taxonomy( $custom_tax_nome, $custom_post_type_nome, $args );
}
```

Coloque esse código nos arquivos do seu plugin ou no seu `functions.php`. Fique atento para a maneira como você batiza seus *Custom Posts* e *Custom Taxonomies*. O uso de palavras como *category* (que deve ser uma palavra reservada no WP) pode ser maléfico.

Mais sobre o método `register_taxonomy()` [no codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Se você quiser adicionar as categorias *default* no *Custom Post*, ou seja, sem registrar uma taxonomia de maneira programática, você pode fornecer essa informação na hora de registrar o *Custom Post*. Vale lembrar que categoria é, basicamente, uma taxonomia. Então, no final das contas, o resultado será o mesmo. O código de registro seria algo como

```
register_post_type('produto',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            //todos os seus labels
            ),

        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        // ...
        //todo o resto dos seus parâmetros de criação
        // ...
        'taxonomies' => array('category'), // <=== habilita o uso de categorias por default

     )
);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua resposta. Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @Diegooli disponha